# Android Cannot play video

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview

We are developing android app (other team developed iOs app). The app is basically sharing videos, now when we record a video and play instantly no problem, but when uploading and then playing it gives as Error "Cannot play video"

Strange thing is that iOs can play android and iOs videos, and in android app cannot play any videos.

Video formats are:
Android - mp4
iOs - mov

Can someone help us?

**EDIT**
Video example: https://sharemestorage.blob.core.windows.net:443/shareme-videos/eed7ec96-c55f-4aa8-bf81-9e22868981a8

Comment: are you trying in Android Emulator ?

Comment: No no, we tried on at least 3 different phones.

Comment: @Kedarnath i added video example